# Unable to print the text using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I want to print out "ou" from this HTML via XPath.

```
<div class="syllable">ou</div>
```

This is my code:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('*my xpath*')
for my_elem in elem:
    print(my_elem.text)
```

I used `.text` in this code but it just prints out nothing when it runs. It should be printing `ou` but it just prints nothing at all. If someone could please tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: Your xpath might be not getting what you actually think you are getting

Comment: Uhm, are we supposed to guess what your xpath is ?

Comment: Please improve your question and show us a bit more of your code, please. that would help aus to reproduce your problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To print the *text* `ou` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.syllable").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='syllable']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.syllable"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='syllable']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ou
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

if you are unable to print the text using .text
then use .get_attribute("innerHTML")
this will defiantly print out the text.

eg.
your code should look like this

```
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('*my xpath*').get_attribute("innerHTML")

    for my_elem in elem:
    print(my_elem)
```